# What is the name of the song that is played during Frieza's regeneration in Dragon Ball Z : Resurrection F?

Tags: music, dragon-ball-z

I saw *Dragon Ball Z: Resurrection F* today in the theatre, and right around the point where Frieza is put in the regeneration machine, a song starts playing. I would categorize the song in the heavy metal genre, and I heard Frieza's name several times in the lyrics as well.

I would like to know the name of this song and the band who played it, as it sounded pretty awesome, but I didn't have enough time to stick around for the credits to see who it was.

Comment: The movie's [OST list](http://dragonblogz.com/dragon-ball-z-resurrection-f-ost-listing/) was released in May 2015. You can check if the track you're looking for exists in that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The song you are looking for is titled 'F' and is performed by Maximum the Hormone.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer, such as a source on where you found your answer, please?

Comment: I can verify that his answer is correct. This sounds exactly like the song I was looking for.

Comment: @Frosteeze I have listened the song before, thus I know the title and the artist.